# Non deterministic AssertionError during deno-test

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, deno

I have the following dummy test case for deno:

```js
Deno.test("Run LS", () => {
  const cmd = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["ls"],
    stdout: "piped",
    stderr: "piped",
  });

  let status: Deno.ProcessStatus, stdout: string, stderr: string;

  const f = async () => {
    const [status_, stdout_, stderr_] = await Promise.all([
      cmd.status(),
      cmd.output(),
      cmd.stderrOutput(),
    ]);
    cmd.close();

    status = status_;
    stdout = new TextDecoder().decode(stdout_);
    stderr = new TextDecoder().decode(stderr_);
  };

  f()
    .then(
      function (result) {
        console.log(`My result: ${result}`);

        console.log(`status: `, status);
        console.log(`stdout: `, stdout);
        console.log(`stderr: `, stderr);

      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(`My error: ${error}`);
      }
    )
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(`My cought error: ${error}`);
    })
    .finally(function () {
      console.log("In the finally clause...");
    });
});
```

When I run it using `deno test --allow-read --allow-run --unstable <filename>` sometimes I get the following correct output:

```
running 1 tests
test fetch pending tasks ... My result: undefined
status:  { success: true, code: 0 }
stdout:  a.ts
<rest of files in the directory>

stderr:
In the finally clause...
ok (7ms)
```

And sometimes I get the following assertion error emitted:

```
running 1 tests
test Run LS ... FAILED (4ms)

failures:

Run LS
AssertionError: Test case is leaking async ops.
Before:
  - dispatched: 0
  - completed: 0
After:
  - dispatched: 5
  - completed: 4

Make sure to await all promises returned from Deno APIs before
finishing test case.
    at assert (deno:runtime/js/06_util.js:34:13)
    at asyncOpSanitizer (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:50:7)
    at async resourceSanitizer (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:74:7)
    at async Object.exitSanitizer [as fn] (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:101:9)
    at async TestRunner.[Symbol.asyncIterator] (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:275:13)
    at async Object.runTests (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:352:22)
    at async file:///home/berger/src/taskwarrior-deno/$deno$test.ts:3:1

failures:

        Run LS
```

If I don't wrap my function in `Deno.test(...)`, and instead I run it as a regular script (i.e., `deno run ...` instead of `deno.test`) then I never get this assertion error.

Is this the right way of calling and using `Deno.run`? If so, is there something else that I'm doing wrong? Is it an error with the way deno itself is running my test case?

BTW, I'm super new to the whole JavaScript ecosystem, so if you have any further suggestion to make regarding the code, feel free to make them.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question as a deno github issue and got the following working version of the above:

Link: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/9767#issuecomment-797466192

```
Deno.test("Run LS", async () => {
  const cmd = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["ls"],
    stdout: "piped",
    stderr: "piped",
  });
  const f = async () => {
    const [status_, stdout_, stderr_] = await Promise.all([
      cmd.status(),
      cmd.output(),
      cmd.stderrOutput(),
    ]);
    cmd.close();

    return {
      status: status_,
      stdout: new TextDecoder().decode(stdout_),
      stderr: new TextDecoder().decode(stderr_),
    };
  };
  try {
    const { status, stderr, stdout } = await f();
    console.log("status:", status);
    console.log("stdout:", stdout);
    console.log("stderr:", stderr);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Caught error:", error);
  }
});
```